# Domain design involving 3 NODES and 1 RELATIONSHIP in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I need to design domain in neo4j for following use case

A PERSON can have many SKILLS . PERSON can work in different Organizations . Each Organization can rank a Person on each SKILL they poses.
Now PersonA have SKILLS SkillA and SkillB . He work on TaskA which require SkillA in OrganizationA and TasKB which requires SkillA in OrganizationB .

How could I design above case in neo4j.

Comment: Wow, lot of neo4j answerers online right now... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
(:Person), (:Organization), (:Skill), (:Ranking), (:Task)

(:Person)-[:works_at]->(:Organization)
(:Organization)-[:gives_ranking]->(:Ranking)
(:Ranking)-[:ranks_person {rank: value}]->(:Person)
(:Ranking)-[:for_skill]->(:Skill)
(:Person)-[:works_on]->(:Task)
(:Task)-[:requires_skill]->(:Skill)
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, it depend on your queries.
As I can imagine usage of your dataset structure, then I maybe choice something like that:

```
(p:Person), (o:Organization), (s:Skill), (t:Task)
(p)-[:WORK_AT]->(o)
(p)-[:WORK_ON]->(t)
(p)-[:HAVE]->(s)
(t)-[:REQUIRE]->(s)
(t)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(o)
```

Comment: You missed connecting the task to the org.

Answer (score 1):

This totally depends on your use cases and what questions you're looking to answer from the graph.

As an example, take a look at the Recruitment GraphGist http://gist.neo4j.org/?0278fc6cbba43c4bf964 which models a subset of your data but from the perspective of recruitment.

Answer (score 1):

In order to properly answer this question, you really need to provide the types of queries that you want to make. Many models are possible, but only some of them may be suitable for making your queries in a performant and/or elegant way.

Here is a sample model that may or may not suit your needs. It adds (to your stated requirements) a node for storing a person's own "claimed skill level" for each skill he says he has. This node allows multiple people to share a single `:Skill` node for each type of skill, while also providing a node per person/skill for the Organization's ratings (`:RATES`) relationships to point to.

```
(:Person)-[:CLAIMS]->(:ClaimedSkillLevel {level:95})-[:FOR]->(:Skill {name: "Java"})<-[:REQURES]-(:Task)<-[:HAS_TASK]-(:Organization)
(:ClaimedSkillLevel)<-[:RATES {rating:75}]-(:Organization)
(:Person)-[:WORKED_ON]->(:Task)
```